# Jira 7.6.0 Only Admin can login, User can't login

Tags: jira

Just installed Jira 7.6.0

2 Groups (`jira-administrators, jira-software-users`)

Issue is that only admin can login, the first user of jira when I've installed Jira. Only that user can login.

If I assign both groups to any user, still getting same error "`Sorry, your username and password are incorrect - please try again`."

I've also tried to change password of user and try to login, but getting same error.

And one query - is this related to `jira-crowd` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It was my mistake. I was trying to log in to Jira with an **email
  address instead of username**.
- Posting an answer because it might help someone who is doing the same
  mistake as mine.